# How to insert a recent search pattern to use for search-and-replace in vim?

Tags: vim, find-and-replace

I've entered some search pattern in vim using `/` command. Now, I want to replace those occurrences I've found with something else.

How do I easily insert the recently used search pattern into the `:%s/` command?

The history (accessible via <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> keys) is separate for search and replace, hence my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> will insert the last search pattern into the current command line.

```
:%s/<C-R>//foo/
```

Comment: What about the last typed one, rather than the last one that enter was pressed on?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply omit the search pattern:

```
:%s//foo
```